# How to use parameter of URL to define route in CodeIgniter?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, callback

The issue is this.  I want to be able to use a parameter of one of my url's to define the route that I want to show.  For example, I have the URL:

.../controller_name/method_name/parameter1

I want to use 'parameter1' to define the route, something like this:

```js
function($1){
 return $route['home'];
} = 'login/plazas/$1';
```

I hope you have understood and thank you for the support.